# Should Bob choose a manager while registering a new company?

Tags: united-states, corporate-law, immigration, limited-liability-company

Bob is an F-2(Student dependent) visa holder in the US who wants to establish a new company. Bob is not entitled to work in the U.S..

According to a video I saw on youtube that you must introduce a manager or show yourself as a manager of the new registered company.

Accordingly, is Bob allowed to establish a company? What impediments may he face in the given scenario?

Answer (score 2):

With an F-2 visa, Bob is not allowed to start or work for a new company. However, Bob is allowed to invest money, so he could provide funding for someone else to start a new company (though his interaction with the company would need to be limited to an investor role).